# snakemake: correct syntax for accessing dictionary values

Tags: python, snakemake

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
mydictionary={
'apple': 'crunchy fruit',
'banana': 'mushy and yellow'
}

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{key}.txt', key=mydictionary.keys())

rule test:
    output: temp('{f}.txt')
    shell:
        """
        echo {mydictionary[wildcards.f]} > {output}
        cat {output}
        """
```

For some reason, I am not able to access the dictionary contents. I tried using double-curly brackets, but the content of the text files becomes literal `{mydictionary[wildcards.f]}` (while I want the content of the corresponding entry in the dictionary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the bracket markup can only replace variables with string representations of their values, but does not support any code evaluation within the brackets. That is, `{mydictionary[wildcards.f]}` will try to look up a variable literally named `"mydictionary[wildcards.f]"`.  Likewise, `{mydictionary}[{wildcards.f}]` will just paste the string values together. So, I don't think you can do what you want within the `shell` section alone.  Instead, you can accomplish what you want in the `params` section:

```
rule test:
    output: temp('{f}.txt')
    params:
        value=lambda wcs: mydictionary[wcs.f]
    shell:
        """
        echo '{params.value}' > {output}
        cat {output}
        """
```